# how to set QLineEdit to readonly if the data mapped by QDataWidgetMapper is readonly?

Tags: qt, pyqt, model-view

I have a tree model and use `QDataWidgetMapper` to map the model data to some widgets.

In the model, some of the data are flagged as read-only, so, what I would like to do is to let the mapped widget, say, a `QLineEdit`, be able to act upon this flag and set itself to readonly when the model data it points to is readonly.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [QDataWidgetMapper.currentIndexChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatawidgetmapper.html#currentIndexChanged)?

Comment: Seems like an interesting feature for QDataWidgetMapper itself... mind suggesting it on the bugtracker?

Comment: @peppe I believe someone already submitted a bug report for Qt 4.8, (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-8409). It was then closed due to the transition of Qt4 to Qt5. I am not familiar with how Qt bug report works, but will look into it when I have time.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you for the suggestion, it should work. I really hope QDataWidgetMapper could understand the flags :(

Answer (score 0):

Qt's `QAbstractDataModel` interface doesn't expose writability of a piece of data as an attribute: there's nothing you can read to know whether an item can be modified or not. One could think of some non-general hacks, such as attempting to write back the current value of the item to check if it can be changed. They are but hacks, e.g. a model fulfilling the contract mandated by Qt might return `true` from `setData` even on a read-only item if the new value equals old value.

If you're using a model that exposes the writability attribute, you'll need to derive from `QDataWidgetMapper` and implement that functionality yourself.

Comment: >>Qt's QAbstractDataModel interface doesn't expose writability of a piece of data<< That's not quite true: there is `QAbstractItemModel::flags()` which should return `Qt::ItemIsEditable` for writable entries in the model and it should omit that flag for read-only entries.